# How do you query the EclipseLink version at runtime (plus JPA meta data)?

Tags: jpa, version, eclipselink

Question pretty much says it all.

Is there an equivalent for `org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString()` in EclipseLink?

Why isn't there a portable (JPA) way to query provider information in general?

Comment: Why there isn't a JPA way of doing that is a question for the JPA "expert group". JDO provides a mechanism for getting the version of JDO implementations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never used it but from the [Eclipselink javadoc](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/index.html) you could try the following class:

> [org.eclipse.persistence.Version](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/Version.html)

Comment: Unfortunately Eclipselink is not well documented. I would like to RTFM if there was any ;-)

Comment: Doesn't work for me... (Package org.eclipse.persistence does not exist)  I'm using Glassfish 4.1 and don't know in which library eclipselink is buried.  Maybe in javaee-endorsed-api-7.0.jar or in javaee-web-api.  Any idea how my web-app can query the eclipselink version?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PierreC, the same thing happened to me: EclipseLink is provided by the runtime but since it's not available at compile time, the package doesn't exist. Solution: use reflection, like this: 
            Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("org.eclipse.persistence.Version");
            Method myMethod = myClass.getMethod("getVersion");
            String version = myMethod.invoke(null).toString();

Answer (score 0):

There is a static class and static method to get this information.

Example: How to print in java code

```
AbstractSessionLog.getLog().log(SessionLog.INFO, DatabaseLogin.getVersion());
```